# Remove repetitive values from a list based on certain conditions

Tags: python, list, unique

I have a list of variables as below

```
roll_off_m4**
ov_offer_desc_m4
curr_ov_tier_desc2_m4
income
age
vid_offer_up_flag_m3
vidpromo_rng_m4*
ovpromo_rng_m4*
ovpromo_rng_m3*
roll_off_m3
roll_off_m2
oolpromo_rng_m3*
ov_offer_group_v2_desc_m4
oolpromo_rng_m2*
rsdvr_orig_m2
vidpromo_rng_m2*
ovpromo_rng_m2*
```

Some, like the ones marked by a * are essentially the same variable but the month in which it's value is taken can be different.
Like roll_off in Feb is m2 , in Mar is m3 and Apr is m4.
I need to pick only the variable corresponding to m2 in case multiple month values are present.
In case only a single month value is present , I pick that only.

In case of variables like age and income, since there is no month info associated with them, I just pick them as is.

All these picked values are appended to a final list of variables.

Can someone please help me to do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I have updated the function to achieve the results you have specified in the comments.

I'm using a pretty long list comprehension, so I'll quickly outline what's being checked to add the item to the output:

1. The variable contains a number and ("_m" + month_number) is in the variable name
2. There is no number in the variable (e.g. 'age')
3. There is no other example of this variable with a different month

So running the code below will output the following for a month variable of '2':

```
['roll_off_m4**', 'ov_offer_desc_m4', 'curr_ov_tier_desc2_m4', 'income', 'age', 'vid_offer_up_flag_m3', 'roll_off_m2', 'ov_offer_group_v2_desc_m4', 'oolpromo_rng_m2*', 'rsdvr_orig_m2', 'vidpromo_rng_m2*', 'ovpromo_rng_m2*']
```

*Full code:*

```
# 're' is imported for determining if the month number is in the variable
import re

# Your initial list of variables
my_list =   ['roll_off_m4**',
             'ov_offer_desc_m4',
             'curr_ov_tier_desc2_m4',
             'income',
             'age',
             'vid_offer_up_flag_m3',
             'vidpromo_rng_m4*',
             'ovpromo_rng_m4*',
             'ovpromo_rng_m3*',
             'roll_off_m3',
             'roll_off_m2',
             'oolpromo_rng_m3*',
             'ov_offer_group_v2_desc_m4',
             'oolpromo_rng_m2*',
             'rsdvr_orig_m2',
             'vidpromo_rng_m2*',
             'ovpromo_rng_m2*']

# This function will return the list for the month specified
def get_data_for_month(month_number, variable_list):
    return [variable for variable in variable_list if (bool(re.search(r'\d', variable)) == True and ("_m" + str(month_number)) in variable) or (bool(re.search(r'\d', variable)) == False) or (variable.replace(variable[variable.find("_m"):variable.find("_m")+3], "_m2")) not in variable_list]


#function call
output = get_data_for_month(2, my_list)

#output is printed
print(output)
```

Comment: Hello @PL200.. Thanks a lot. However, this does not take of variables like ov_offer_group_v2_desc_m4, which should also come in the output since there are no other months associated with it.

Comment: @ShuvayanDas Apologies, but isn't the '_m4' at the end indicating that month 4 (April) is associated with it?

Comment: ,, Yes it does. But , as I mentioned in the question, in cases where single month values are present, it is taken as it is. Only when other months along with m2 are present, I need to select the m2 ones.I am sorry if the question is not clear.

Comment: That is not very clear. So are you saying that if there is only one example of 'm6', it should also be picked up?

Comment: Yes @PL200.. That is right.. The reason is, several months appearing together basically means duplicate. So, need to pick only m2.

Comment: @ShuvayanDas Okay, sure. I have updated my code in the post to reflect what you've asked. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PL200.. The code construct is a little complex for me to understand, however I understand what it is essentially doing, based on your explanations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ShuvayanDas No problem, glad to have helped. I do apologies for the complexity, it is probably better suited for simple loops. However studying this is a good foray into list comprehension, if nothing else

Comment: Hello @PL200.. Yes this will surely help me in improving my python skills.. Thanks a lot!!